# why does" is" in this clause time become "would" in the past

Tags: past-tense

" it will be up to seventy-two hours until it is ready" present

reported speech:
He said that it would be up to seventy-two hours hours until it **would be** ready  Why "would be" instead of was, is it because it is a reported speech, is it a rule to change "is" with" would" in the past for a clause time.

Comment: _till it was ready_ seems fine to me although in fact I usually say _until_ not _till_. But _would be_ is also fine as far as I can see.

Comment: I prefer "seventy-two hours" in direct and reported speech.

Comment: what do you think of that comment: Strictly speaking, that example should be ...and was told [that] it would be [up to] 72 hours until it would be ready for pickup. Uneducated (or just "careless") native speakers might use Simple Past was rather than "hypothetical future within the past" would be. this comment was made by FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica